# Regex to specific rule

Tags: php, regex, perl, postal-code

I need to recreate this logic using regex.

if $postcode.length > 0 and $postcode.length < 10 AND
$postcode's first character is a letter and (second or third character is a number) then it's a match.

I came up with this following regex:

/((^[a-z]+[0-9]?[0-9]){1,9}$)/i

It needs to match these examples:

- B1 8PT
- SW12 TQ1
- B12 TYP
- A1AAAAAAA
- AA1AAAAAA

Edited:
My current regex doesn't match any of the examples on the list. I can't figure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So whats the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a pattern:

```
^[A-Z](?=.?\d)[A-Z0-9 ]{0,8}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT3wV5/2).

I used the lookahead `(?=.?\d)` to check the second or third character to see if it's a digit.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change it to {0,8} and worked fine with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

With an alternation:

```
/^[a-z](?:[0-9].{0,7}|.[0-9].{0,6})$/i
```